# numpy, how to be more elegant?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the nicer/shorter way to write this using numpy.
both img have the same shape and type.
Haven't used this too much

```
def cut_whole(img_to_cut, img_to_use):
    #we assume unit8 dtype
    assert img_to_cut.shape==img_to_use.shape

    #iterate all,assume shape is (:,:,4)
    (x,y,c)=img_to_cut.shape
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            if(img_to_use[i,j,3]>0):
                img_to_cut[i,j,:]=0    
    return img_to_cut
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
img_to_cut[img_to_use[:, :, 3:4] > 0] = 0
```

Note that selecting the last channel is done in such a way as to retain a third axis of length one; that allows the resulting boolean mask to broadcast to the other array.